# Expressing the homomorphism condition with a commutative diagram.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am asking myself how to express the homomorphic condition in commutative diagrams. For this let $(M, \cdot)$ and $(N, \cdot)$ be algebraic structures and let $\varphi : M \to N$ be a homomorphism, then for all $x,y \in M$
$$
 \varphi(x \cdot y) = \varphi(x) \circ \varphi(y).
$$
The only possiblity that comes to my mind is

$$\begin{matrix} M\times M & \overset{\varphi\times\varphi}{\longrightarrow} & N\times N \\  \downarrow {\scriptsize \cdot}& & \downarrow {\scriptsize \circ} \\ M \,\,\,& \overset{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} & N\end{matrix}$$

where $(\varphi \times \varphi)(x,x) := (\varphi(x), \varphi(x))$. But this seems quite complicated with all this products to express this simple idea, so are there simpler diagrams to express this (when mine is right, don't know if it is valid to assume that such product constructions are possible...)?

Comment: From what I can see, that diagram is indeed commutative.  I'm not sure how much simpler you can make it (or are hoping to make it), considering you are using only the necessary binary operations.  Also, what do you mean when you say that you don't know if it is valid to assume that such product constructions are possible?

Comment: This diagram does indeed express that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. If you're worried about assuming products exist, this is OK because an algebraic structure is by definition a set with some binary operations on it, and as such admits a forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$. Unless I'm overlooking something, this means that the product in whatever category you start in should just be the set theoretic product in $\mathsf{Set}$, but with some extra structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, and it's as simple as it's going to get. This is a special case of a homomorphism of [algebras for an endofunctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra), which has exactly the same diagram but generalised. I'll explain below.

Let $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ be a functor from a category $\mathcal{C}$ to itself. An $F$-*algebra* is a pair $(M, \alpha)$, where $\alpha : FM \to M$ is a morphism, which may be required to satisfy some additional properties. In your case we have $FM = M \times M$ and $\alpha(x,y) = x \cdot y$.

A *homomorphism* of $F$-algebras $\phi : (M, \alpha) \to (N, \beta)$ is a morphism $\phi : M \to N$ making the following diagram commute:
$$\begin{matrix} FM & \overset{F\phi}{\rightarrow} & FN \\ {\scriptsize \alpha} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptsize \beta} \\ M & \underset{\phi}{\rightarrow} & N\end{matrix}$$

That is, $f$ is a homomorphism so long as it kind-of-commutes with $\phi$, where by kind-of-commutes I mean you need to stick an $F$ in there.

In summary, here we have:

- $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of whatever algebraic structures you're working with
- $M$ and $N$ are objects of this category
- $F$ is the diagonal product functor, defined by $FM = M \times M$ and $F\phi = \phi \times \phi$
- $\alpha : M \times M \to M$ is the morphism $(x,y) \mapsto x \cdot y$
- $\beta : N \times N \to N$ is the morphism $(x,y) \mapsto x \circ y$

**[Added]** I guess the point of me saying all this, which I forgot to make explicit, was to respond to the part where you said

> "But this seems quite complicated with all [these] products to express this simple idea"

The fact of the matter is that 'all these products' all come from *one* thing, namely the diagonal functor ${({-})} \times {({-})}$, which plays the role of the endofunctor $F$ in the above construction.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. After some thought I think the reason why such conditions are never stated categorically (but as a sidenote I have very limited knowledge in this area of math) is that a category is by definition something with all the morphism, where what these morphism are or what they satisfy is not stated, for example in *Sets* they are just bijections, so the law they satisfy is $|dom(f)| = |f(dom(f))|$, and in *Group* they are the homomorphism, and then the law they satisfy is $f(gh) = f(g)f(h)$.