# Isomorphisms of $\mathbb{N}$ split to countable sequences of pairs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

This is homework.

Let $f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, $g: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be fixed point-free involutions, that is, $f(f(n)) = n$, $f(n)\neq n$ for all $n$, and same holds for $g$.

Need to prove that the structures $\mathcal{M} = (\mathbb{N}, f)$ and $\mathcal{N} = (\mathbb{N}, g)$ are isomorphic, i.e. that there exists a bijection $\pi:\text{dom}(\mathcal{M}) \to \text{dom} (\mathcal{N})$ such that $g\circ\pi = \pi\circ f$.

Update: removed my own previous too complex attempts to solve this.

Update: I believe something in the spirit of the following should work:

\begin{align*}
\pi(m) =
\begin{cases}
\min(\dots) & \text{if } m < f(m) \\
\max(\dots) & \text{if } m > f(m)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The idea is as follows. Involutions split $\mathbb{N}$ in pairs. When sending a pair to its counterpart pair, we should be consistent in that smaller element of a pair in $\text{dom}(\mathcal{M})$ is sent to the smaller element of the corresponding pair in the domain of the other structure. We can of course also flip the sides, but key is consistency.

Comment: What does "isomorphic" mean in this context?  Do you mean:  there must be a bijection $F:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ such that $f\circ F=F^{-1}\circ g$?  Something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this. Question updated.

Comment: I would say an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{N}, f)$ to $(\mathbb{N}, g)$ is a bijection $F : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $\forall x, F(f(x)) = g(F(x))$.  And a homomorphism is the same thing but not necessarily a bijection.

Comment: @GEdgar  I agree, that's better.  And (from the edit) it appears to be what the OP had in mind...not sure why they agreed with my other suggestion.

Comment: @GEdgar and Lulu, could you explain me why an homomorphism from $(\Bbb N,f)$ to $(\Bbb N,g)$ is a function $F:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that $F(f(x))=g(F(x))\,$? Why is it the correct definition ? I need to understand it. Could you explain it by means of the usual homomorphism of algebraic structures such as groups ?

Comment: Oh, I just subconsciously ignored the inverse mapping in the first comment from @lulu :)

Comment: @Angelo  If $f:A\to A$ and $g:B\to B$ are functions, then, with $F:A\to B$ you can make a square diagram with $F$ on top and bottom and $f,g$ on the sides.  The condition just says this square commutes.

Comment: @lulu, what do you mean when you say “the square conmutes” ? And what does that have to do with the usual homomorphism of algebraic structures such as groups, rings, fields, etc ?

Comment: @Angelo  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610866/expressing-the-homomorphism-condition-with-a-commutative-diagram) is a parallel description of homomorphisms in this language.  And [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CommutativeDiagram.html) is a general introduction to commutative diagrams.  Should say, I don't think the definition is entirely obvious in this case, which is why I asked the OP to supply one.

Comment: @lulu, thank you very much for your good explanation, now I can understand what that has to do with the usual homomorphism of groups. I am sorry, but for me it was not clear at all before now.

Comment: @DamianVårfågelberg, in the second case, that is, $m<f(m)$ and $n>f(n)$, it is obvious that $m\neq n$, moreover $\pi(m)=\pi(n)$ is equivalent to $g(m)=f(n)$ which could be true. In fact I think that it is possible to get some counterexample, that is, two fixed point-free involutions $f$ and $g$ on $\Bbb N$ such that $m<f(m)$, $n>f(n)$ and $g(m)=f(n)$, consequently $\pi(m)=\pi(n)$ should not imply $m=n$. Analogously, in the third case, I think it is possible that $\pi(m)=\pi(n)$ even though $m\neq n$. Please, could you try to get a counterexample as regards the second or the third case?

Comment: @DamianVårfågelberg, do not remove your attempts and efforts otherwise your post will turn to a very low-quality question and will be closed. Please put your attempts and efforts again before it is too late.

Comment: @Angelo, thanks for comment, I am preparing the final good answer, which I believe should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making things too complicated. With the given hypotheses, $f$ and $g$ have the same cycle decomposition, namely countably many cycles of length $2$. So it suffices to choose any bijection between these cycles. E.g. if $f$ has cycle decomposition $(12)(34)(56)(78) \dots$ and $g$ has cycle decomposition, say, $(13)(58)(27)(46) \dots $ then $\pi$ needs to send $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $5$, and so on.

This requires no casework. The more general fact is that if $f, g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ are two bijections then they are conjugate iff they have the same cycle decomposition, exactly as in the finite case, where the multiplicity of a cycle length may be infinite and you also need to consider infinite cycles.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Yes, I understood the splitting, what I failed to figure out is to how to actually build the bijection $\pi$. When saw your notation in the language of permutations, the needed construction popped up immediately in my head. So thank you again!